# Joining two tables via primary key in first table sql

Tags: sql, select, join

I would like to join these two tables by the locationID  which is a primary key in the holiday table and select rows from the whole joined table

[image]

i would like a select all query, where you can select rows from both tables which match if you perform the result set operation.

How would you do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    Accomodation a
        INNER JOIN Holiday b
            ON a.LocationID = b.LocationID
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: What does a and b represent?

Comment: They are called `ALIAS`. They are useful when you have longer table names `:D`

Comment: @user1992697: although using meaningless aliases is considered bad programming style (at least by some people). You'd better use an abbreviation that contains some reference to the original table, e.g `acc` and `hol` instead of `a`, `b`.

Comment: Would you by any chance know how to join and delete?

Answer (score 0):

```
       SELECT * FROM Holiday INNER JOIN
             Accommodation ON Holiday.LocationId= Accommodation.LocationId
```